# Pre fill WkWebView textfields

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have a weblink which I open from the app in a WkWebView .
I need to pre-populate textfield on the webpage using Swift

The textFiled in the web looks like this

```
<input type="tel" name="cardNumber" ui-mask="9999999999999999999" ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" class="form-control" ng-model="cardDetails.cardNumber" required-message="'Please enter your Gift Card number.'" invalid-message="'Please enter valid 19 digit Gift Card number.'" validate-on="blur" maxlength="19" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{19,19}$/" require
```

I tried couple of codes but didn't work , it gives an output as shown in the image below

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('cardNumber')[0].value = '9999999999999999';") { (result, error) in
}
```

[image]

Here is the link I am trying to set values for

https://giftcards.woolworths.com.au/check-balance

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I am not able to set the value of a textfield in wkwebview

Comment: @QueshiZakir If you're not able to set the value, how come there is a prefilled text field in the UI with the value "9999999999999999" ?